# how to query Hive from Spark on CDH 5.4.4

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'm runnning CDH 5.4.4 (which bundles Spark 1.3.0) and would like to read a Hive table into a Spark dataframe.

Looking at the documentation, it suggests that we can do the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
results = sqlContext.sql("SHOW TABLES").collect()
```

... providing that Spark has been built with `-Phive` and `-Phive-thriftserver` flags set.

I'm not sure whether Cloudera's build has those flags set.

When I run the snippet, it returns the following error:

```
15/07/10 16:54:10 WARN HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default database after error: Error creating transactional connection factory
  javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
```

I have two questions:

1. does Cloudera's Spark build have the `hive` and `hive-thriftserver` flags set?
2. what do I need to do to query Hive from Spark?

**Update**

This almost works:

I created a symlink from `$SPARK_HOME/conf/` to `hive-site.xml`, i.e.

```
ln -s /etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/hive-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml
```

I then restarted the Spark service and was able to access Hive. Unfortunately, the symlink didn't survive a reboot.

Comment: Not sure if this is a help to you , but your code works for me on Amazon EMR out of the box... so one option would be to use EMR? Also maybe check that `results` definitely didn't get created -- for me when i ran the command i still got some "error" messages, and yet the correct output was still created.

Comment: Thanks @maxymoo. It's encouraging to hear that it works on AWS. In this case, I have a lot of data and so it'd be expensive and time-consuming to move it to AWS. Also, having made the investment in my own hardware, it'd be an own-goal to run up an AWS bill. Appreciate the thought/suggestion.

Comment: no worries, and glad you're getting closer. what do you mean "doesn't survive a reboot"? did you try putting that line in your `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 0):

copy hive-site.xml from hive conf to spark conf.dist as shown in below,

```
sudo cp /etc/impala/conf.dist/hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf.dist/
```

now try you able to read hive data from pyspark